# Xcode debugger stopped responding

Tags: xcode, debugging, lldb

I'm seeing some truly bizarre behaviour from lldb in one of my projects. When I stop execution at a breakpoint and enter anything at all in the debugging console, there is no response:

[image]

I'm running a debug build here. The issue does not occur in other projects, where I can debug without issue.

This is a real head-scratcher. Has anybody run into this before?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue, but in an unsatisfying manner; by getting a fresh clone from git.

I suppose one of the files in the standard Xcode .gitignore got weird and caused this behaviour.

Comment: There's a popup at the bottom of the Xcode Debug console window that controls what gets printed to the window.  The normal setting is "All Output" but if that is switched to "Target Output" then you won't see the debugger command output - just as you showed.  Since the value of this setting is stored in the project, it would get reset on a fresh checkout.  That sounds to me like what happened, though there's no way to tell now.  Anyway, if this happens again, that's something to check for, and if it's getting set inadvertently, it would be good to figure out how.